# Kotlin Filter list according to another list

Tags: kotlin, filtering

I have a list of all market types, and a list of all markets (each object having a market typeId)

I want to have a market type list containing only the market types in the all markets list (without having the market types duplicated). How to do so?

Here's my code:

```
for (i in marketsFilter.indices) {
    val market = marketsFilter[i]
    marketTypes.add(MyApplication.allMarketTypes.single { 
        it.id == market.marketTypeId 
    })
}
```

Comment: check please the edited answer

Comment: this code you are getting duplicate values?

Answer (score 2):

You can express that more concise using `map`:

```
marketsFilter.map { market ->
   MyApplication.allMarketTypes.single { it.id == market.marketTypeId }
}.distinct()
```

No need to handle raw indices.

Note: If you want to use [single](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/single.html) dependes on your use case, take a look the list below and decide for yourself.

---

[`single`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/single.html): Returns the single element matching the given predicate, or throws exception if there is no or more than one matching element.

[`singleOrNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/single-or-null.html): Returns the single element matching the given predicate, or `null` if element was not found or more than one element was found.

[`first`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/first.html): Returns the first element matching the given predicate or throws an exception if there is none.

[`firstOrNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/first-or-null.html): 
Returns the first element matching the given predicate, or `null` if element was not found.

If you decide to use a `...OrNull` variant use [`mapNotNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-not-null.html) to discard the null values.

```
marketsFilter.mapNotNull { market ->
    // ...
}.distinct()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i in marketsFilter.indices) {
     val market = marketsFilter[i]
     marketTypes.add(
         MyApplication.allMarketTypes.single { it.id == market.marketTypeId })
}

marketTypes = marketTypes.distinct().toMutableList()
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in the following:

```
val marketTypes = marketsFilter.mapNotNull { market ->
                                  MyApplication.allMarketTypes
                                                        .singleOrNull { it.id == market.marketTypeId }
                               }.distinct().toMutableList()
```

You may also be interested in the vice-versa approach, basically filtering just the market types for the ids of the market filter, e.g.:

```
val marketTypes = MyApplication.allMarketTypes.filter { type -> marketsFilter.any { it.marketTypeId == type.id } }
                                              .toMutableList() // no distinct needed
```

You may also want to replace any `.distinct().toMutableList()` with a [`.toMutableSet()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-mutable-set.html) if that also suites your needs.

Note also, if you check your `allMarketTypes` often, you may rather want to put them in a map, e.g.:

```
val allMarketTypesMap = allMarketTypes.associateBy { it.id }
```

That way your further mappings will become much easier, e.g.:

```
val marketTypes = marketsFilter.mapNotNull { allMarketTypesMap[it.marketTypeId] }
                               .distinct().toMutableList() // or just .toMutableSet()
```

As a side-note regarding duplicates in the `allMarketTypes` (in case there are any): [`associateBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/associate-by.html#associateby) will collect just the last of all entries with the same id, basically discarding any duplicate market type. [`single`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/single.html) on the other hand will basically fail if there are more then one market type with same id or none (or if you use [`singleOrNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/single-or-null.html) it will instead return `null`). Just keep that in mind.